# Check if a element doesn't contain a certain class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find out a way to in javascript to check if an element doesn't contain a certain class. Basically I want to find out the opposite of `elements.classList.contains("class")`
I want to check if it doesn't contain. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `!elements.classList.contains("class")` - [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

Comment: Using [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) is actually simpler approach...`!element.matches('.someClass')`

Comment: @charlietfl `element.matches(':not(.someClass)')`?